# How to connect button to form submission using Material UI Cards?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple form which is inside a material ui [Card](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) component....

```
 import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
 import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
 import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';

return (
<Card className={classes.card}>
  <CardContent>
        <form id="login" className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField id="username" label="User Name" />
            <TextField id="password" label="Password" />
        </form>
  </CardContent>
  <CardActions>
    <Button size="small">Submit</Button>
  </CardActions>
</Card>
)
```

How can I connect the Submit button inside the 'CardActions' component to the form in the 'CardContent' component (so that clicking it will cause handleSubmit to get called)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you might just be able to wrap the entire thing in the form tag and it would work if you add a type="submit". Alternatively you can add an onClick to your button and handle it with a method, either will work. I haven't tested what I posted below but it might do the trick.

```
 import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
 import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
 import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';

return (
<Card className={classes.card}>
  <CardContent>
        <form id="login" className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField id="username" label="User Name" />
            <TextField id="password" label="Password" />
            <CardActions>
               <Button size="small" type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </CardActions>
        </form>
  </CardContent>

</Card>
)
```

Comment: Your solution worked, as a follow up, could I ask how the data from the form can be read in handleSubmit event handler?

Comment: well you would just add an onClick={() => this.handleClick()} to the Button component. The handleClick would be a method that you would have to define in your component. You would also need to worry about setting state when the fields are updated or changed, like the username and pw TextFields. Then you can do error checking and stuff like that, either when the fields are changed or when the button is pressed.

Comment: I'm new to mui and couldn't find where the 'type' prop was defined on the button's api.  Is this explained anywhere explicitly ?  like maybe the docs explain somewhere that wrappers to native elements also expose native attributes as props ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `component` property of `Card` instead of the `form` element (and move your form attributes):

```
<Card component="form" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="login" className={classes.card}>
  <CardContent className={classes.form}>
    <TextField id="username" label="User Name" />
    <TextField id="password" label="Password" />
  </CardContent>
  <CardActions>
    <Button size="small">Submit</Button>
  </CardActions>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use refs to grab your form, and submit it manually.

```
import {useRef} from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
 import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
 import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';

return (


const formRef = useRef(null);
const connectButton = () => {
    formRef.current.submit();
}



<Card className={classes.card}>
  <CardContent>
        <form ref={formRef} id="login" className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField id="username" label="User Name" />
            <TextField id="password" label="Password" />
        </form>
  </CardContent>
  <CardActions>
    <Button onClick={connectButton} size="small">Submit</Button>
  </CardActions>
</Card>
)
```

alternatively.

```
<button form='login' type="submit" size="small">Button</button>
```

Comment: I dont think its good practice to use refs like this when you can just use a simple function which in general is a much better solution. Taking advantage of type="submit" is probably best if it works in the situation.

Comment: I've assumed <CardContent> has styling which will break the layout for OP by wrapping the form, and is likely the original reason for the query. having a button outside the form that submits it suggests that the layout has it well and truly outside the main flow. otherwise, you'd naturally stick it inside.